# Node Mongoose, Cast to ObjectId failed for value "N" at path "PATH"

Tags: database, node.js, express, mongoose

Trying to setup a mongoose database for a Node Express application, some of my documents have records that need to reference other collections.

I'm aware that Mongoose provides the `populate` method for filling these sort of relations, but I'm having difficulty setting it up. As far as I can see, I need to specify my schema as so...

```
bookingSchema = mongoose.Schema
  _id:        Number
  # Involved users
  __booker:     {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
```

...but when I attempt to seed the database with __booker values such as 1, 2, 3 (all of which are valid documents in the User collection) get the error...

`Cast to ObjectId failed for value "3" at path "__booker"`

I would assume integers or integer strings should be easily coerced to an ObjectId, but can't seem to get this working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've written this question as the above situation froze me for hours. Massive irritation and it turns out the solution is quite simple and inside the mongoose docs, just as a single one liner. Can't imagine I'm the only one encountering this though, hence posting the answer.

It would appear that mongoose won't be happy with casting your types for _ids. People are likely to run into this problem if they are creating databases that have seeded values that specify relations to each other. I was trying to seed with the Number type as my reference to the other models, as I believed mongoose would cast that to the correct type for the ids. It won't.

If a User looks like this...

```
userSchema = mongoose.Schema
  _id:        Number
  fname:      String
```

...and your post looks like this...

```
postSchema = mongoose.Schema
  _id:    Number
  __user:  {type: Number, ref: 'User'}
```

Then you need to give this as your UserSchema.

```
bookingSchema = mongoose.Schema
  _id:        Number
  # Involved users
  __booker:     {type: Number, ref: 'User'}
```

Note the type is **Number**, not **ObjectId**. This will allow the populate function to operate correctly on your model instances.

Hope this helps, I'm off to hit my head against the wall!